# Can not access the mBuffer of android.graphics.Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I use the following code：

```
Bitmap myBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap( 720, 1280, Config.ARGB_8888 );
byte []data = myBmp.mBuffer ????
```

But I found that mBuffer can not be accessed. And there is no hint that it can not be accessed in Eclipse. What is the problem?

Comment: It's a private variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to the pixels, use

```
Bitmap.getPixel(int,int)
```

and

```
Bitmap.setPixel(int,int)
```

Is this what you want to do?

**EDIT:** The 'problem' is the Java annotation `@hide` which hides the member annotated from code completion and induces errors which stop eclipse from compiling.

Comment: Hey @Bondax, so even if you convert bitmap to a byte array you can't necessarily tell whether mBuffer was null or not.

Comment: @toobsco42: I'm not sure what you are trying to tell / ask. But the only case `mBuffer` can be null is if your bitmap has size (0,0), but even then you have to check whether `mBuffer` is null or `mBuffer.length` is 0. What are you trying to do with that buffer anyways?

Comment: The thing is you can't access this private member variable `mBuffer`.  I attempted to do `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` and it returned a `Bitmap` not just null.  When i look at the mBuffer member variable of the `Bitmap` it is null.  So if i try setting an `ImageView` with `setBitmap()` it fails to set the `ImageView`.

Comment: @toobsco42: Ok, what are you trying to do? What for exactly do you need access to mBuffer other than what `setPixel()` and `getPixel()` can do for you? Do you want to send/receive your bitmap through a Stream and therefore do you need the bitmap's raw data?

Comment: So the call to setBimap() failed, without force closing.  Initially I was thinking my `Bitmap` was null but it was not.  Then i took a look at the `mBuffer` field of this `Bitmap` and that member field was null.  So I wanted to be able to do a check to see if the `Bitmap` was valid before calling `setBitmap()` on the `ImageView`.